# Getting totals deep in associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to get into the Rails3 mindset, and had an interesting problem.

I have the following structure:

- User has_many Tasks
- Task has_many Assets
- Asset has a score attribute between 0 and 99

I'd like to get a sum of all scores for each user, and I suspect scopes might be something useful...

Answer (score 1):

This should be all you need:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tasks
  has_many :assets, through: :tasks

  def score_sum
    assets.pluck(:score).inject(:+)
  end


  # pre rails 3.2, try this:
  def score_sum
    assets.select(:score).map(&:score).inject(:+)
  end
end
```

Comment: this didn't work out, mainly because I think pluck works on `ActiveRecord::Relation`. I got the error `undefined method 'pluck'`.

Comment: It should work with the relation. What version of rails are you using? I believe it was added in 3.2.

Comment: Ahh, I'm stuck at 3.1. Makes sense. Thanks, @zach.

Comment: Thanks for the 3.1 edit. I'm in the throes of updating. It's not going well